# Disk usage warning in root

Tags: partitioning, mount, snap, disk-usage

I freshly installed Ubuntu using 20GB for my root filesystem. After installing software (using snap) I receive disk usage warnings from the Gnome notifier system (less than 1GB). When I run

```
du -hx -d 1 /
```

It says that I had 6GB left. So I wonder if there is a way to change the notifier arguments or if the message still has relevance. I am aware that snap just mounts software so I wonder if there is a away to store the image in my home.

Edit:
Output of lsblk | grep -v loop

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme1n1     259:0    0 238,5G  0 disk 
├─nvme1n1p1 259:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme1n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p3 259:3    0 231,1G  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p4 259:4    0   700M  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p5 259:5    0   5,5G  0 part 
└─nvme1n1p6 259:6    0  1000M  0 part 
nvme0n1     259:7    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:8    0   487M  0 part [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p2 259:9    0  18,6G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:10   0 446,7G  0 part /home
```

Output du -hx -d 1

```
13M /etc
13M /opt
96K /snap
4,0K    /mnt
7,7G    /usr
8,0K    /media
4,0K    /cdrom
4,0K    /srv
131M    /tmp
135M    /boot
332K    /root
8,5G    /var
16K /lost+found
17G /
```

Comment: You have an encrypted partition? Then a separate /boot partition that runs full may be the cause. 20GB for a root partition of Ubuntu is plenty for the system files and user configuration data. Besides, you have 6 GB left, so the problem is not there. Include the full output of du in your question (use "edit") and the output of `lsblk | grep -v loop` (lists all your mounted partitions without the loop devices)

Comment: I added the command outputs like you suggested. I just wonder why I get this notification when there is still enough space on my disk.

Comment: It is an 18,6 G root partition, and 17 G is occupied. Some overhead is reserved for root, so your free user space may indeed be below 1 GB. You use a lot of space on root. Perhaps you have very large log files, which can take up several GB.

Comment: Thanks. I had a look into /var/log and deleted a large journal file. But this only freed up 1GB. /var/lib/snapd/snaps takes around 5GB of my system and /var/lib/docker. Is there a way to move these directory to my home?

Comment: This helped with /var/lib/snapd.
Now I just need to fix the docker part.
Is there a way to prevent logs from blowing up?